# Is {0:{"id":1,...},{"id:2,....}} a other reprensation of a JSON list like [{"id":1,...},{"id:2,....}]

Tags: json, symfony, dart, fosrestbundle

I have a little dilema. I have a backend/Frontend Application that comunicates with a JSON based REST Api.

The backend is written in PHP(Symfony/jmsserializer) and the Frontend in Dart

The communication between these two has a little Problem.

For most List Data the backend responds with a JSON like

```
[{"id":1,...},{"id:2,....}]
```

But for some it responds with

```
{"0":{"id":1,...}, "1":{"id:2,....}}
```

Now my Question is should the backend respond with the later at all or only with the first?

Comment: *But for some it responds with* - what does that mean? Then I guess the data structure is different? The two responses are different for sure.

Comment: It should not be different. They both use the same Symfony Service only with a different Entity Class as Parameter.

Comment: Seems more like a PHP problem than a Dart problem then.

Comment: Oh .. you edited your answer from "0" to 0 ... In dart JSON map keys are always String, thus the actual object representation is different, because string key -> Map and int key -> List.

Comment: Yes and no. It's more a problem of the Library I used not acounting for the fact that not all Lists of objects come in JSON-List notation and the PHP Library I used in the Backend for some reason spitting out object notation JSON when instead it should spit out list notation JSON. But the Dart Decoder works just like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

You usually have a list of objects. You sometimes get an object with sub-objects as properties.

### Underlying issue

JS/JSON-Lists are ordered from 0 upwards which means that if you have PHP-Array which does not respect this rule `json_encode` will output a JS/JSON-Object instead using the numeric indices as keys.

PHP-Arrays are ordered maps which have more features that the JSON-Lists. Whenever you're using those extra features you won't be able to translate directly into JSON-Lists without loosing some information (ordering, keys, skipped indices, etc.).

PHP-Arrays and JSON-Objects on the other hand are more ore less equivalent in terms of features and can be correctly translated between each other without any loss of information.

### Occurence

This happens if you have an initial PHP-Array of values which respects the JS/JSON-List rules but the keys in the list of objects are modified somehow. For example if you have a custom indexing order `{"3":{}, "0":{}, "1":{}, "2":{}}` or if you have (any) keys that are strings (ie. not numeric).

This always happens if you want to use the numeric id of the object as the numeric index of the list `{"123":{"id": 123, "name": "obj"}}` even if the numeric ids are in ascending order... so long as they are not starting from 0 upwards it's not a json-list it's a json-object.

### Specific case

So my guess is that the PHP code in the backend is doing something like fetching a list of objects but its modifying something about it like inserting them by (string) keys into the array, inserting them in a specific order, removing some of them.

### Resolution

The backend can easily fix this by using `array_values($listOfObjects)` before using `json_encode` which will reindex the entire list by numeric indices of ascending value.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok So it is still a List just in object notation. due to it being more complicated than just a list. That makes sense. Still i find it odd that FosRest Modifies the Array index when its only purpose is to render the objects inside the array as an array so that json_encode can render everything. I'll file a bug with them about that. Thank you for your informative answer.

Comment: One example: in Doctrine2 you can (for example) fetch a list of objects as an array and specify a unique indexing column (ex. the ID) and the resulting array will have the id column as key for each row fetched.
Another example: the backend fetches 10 items but delivers 6 because some of them are not accessible to you (by acl) or some of them have some kind of "deleted flag" etc..

Comment: I really can't know what their reasons could be for modifying the content they retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays and dictionaries are two separate types in JSON ("array" and "object" respectively), but PHP combines this functionality in a single array type.

PHP's json_encode deals with this as follows: an array that only contains numeric keys (`$array = ['cat', 'dog']`) is serialized as JSON array, an associative array that contains non-numeric keys (`$array = ['cat' => 'meow', 'dog' => 'woof']`) is serialized as JSON object, including the array's keys in the output.

If you end up with an associative array in PHP, but want to serialize it as a plain array in JSON, just use this to convert it to a numerical array before JSON encoding it: `$array = array_values($array);`

Comment: Yep thats true. Unfortuantly it turns out that FOSRest turns non-associative arrays into associative ones even if array_values is used on the array beforehand.

Comment: Right. I found a related bug report, perhaps one of the workarounds listed there will work for you: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/373